# Sending an Intent from Google Assistant to my smartphone

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I would like to do the following:

- give a command to (the Google Assistant in) Google Home
- from there, send an Intent to my Android smartphone starting an application (on a specific Activity)

Is that possible with Google actions?

I've scanned https://developers.google.com/actions/ but it is not clear to me whether I can send Intents to my phone.  If so, can you provide a pointer?

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Comment: Try and split the puzzle into multiple parts.  When you speak, Google Assistant attempts to "match" an intent.  Once matched, a "fulfillment" is executed associated with the intent.  A fulfillment is commonly a Webhook piece of code on a Webserver.  Now imagine that the webserver was invoked ... try and solve for the puzzle "How would I get an app running on my phone?".    Maybe have a study of "IFTTT" and see if that has any pre-cooked hooks.

Comment: @Kolban  Thanks for your feedback.   So it is not possible to create a fulfillment that sends an Android Intent directly to the smartphone?  I don't think IFTTT has a "then" for an Android Device to start a specific application.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do this. Here are a few ways to get close to the desired behavior:

1. When an intent is triggered on your Assistant surface, send a push notification to your phone (will require [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/)). This push notification can then start an intent.
2. You can use a helper in the Action to [request a new surface](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) with a screen capability. This will not send an intent for your app, but will move the conversation over to a new surface which may make more sense. (This new surface may be able to present a [Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) with a deeplink into your app)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and suggestions!